# Get a highlighted text in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cursor, nscontrol

I'm trying to get the StringValue of any text (Out side my application) that has been selected by the cursor.
I tried checking on NSControl class,but i didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string
```